# CSS is not working with PDF not bale to get alignment and border properly.

Tags: pdf, css

I have VF page which I am rendering as pdf. I wrote some css for alignment div. The alignment of div is correct in VF page. But when I convert the page to pdf all the alignment get changed. I have added border to table inside div, even that is not getting displayed. 
[image]

In need the table to be display like this but I my pfd I am getting table one under another and with out border. I made a lot of changes all get affected on VF page not on pfd. Please help me to get the solution for this issue. 
My VF page code:

```
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">  
        .mainOutpanalstyle{

            width           :   100%;
            display         :   table; 
        }      
        form{
            padding         :   2%;
        }
        .headingStyle{
            padding-left    :   20%; 
            font-size       :   150%;       
            font-weight     :   bold;
        }
        table#tableStyle{
            border          :   1px solid black;


            font-size       :   150%; 
        }
        table#tableStyle_opp{
            border          :   1px solid black;


            font-size       :   150%; 

        }
        div#oppinnnerdivID{
            float:right;

        }
        div#enduserinnnerdivID{
            float:left;
        }
        tr, td{

            padding-left    :   1%;

        }
        th{
            padding-left    :   1%;

        }
        tr#heading{  
        }
        div#enduserdivID{
            padding-top     :   10%;

        }
        div#resellerdivID{
            padding-top     :   10%;

        }
        div#oppdivID{
            padding-top     :   10%;



        }
    </style>
</head>    

<apex:form id="mainformID" >    
    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Parallels_Logo)}"/> 
    <br/>
        <apex:outputText id="headID" value="Parallels Special Pricing Authorization" styleclass="headingStyle"></apex:outputText>
    <br/>

    <apex:outputPanel id="mainOutpanalID" styleClass="mainOutpanalstyle">

        <!-- Table for Enduser Information -->
        <div id="enduserdivID">
            <div id="enduserinnnerdivID">
            <table id="tableStyle">
                <body>
                    <tr id="heading">
                        <th>Enduser Information:</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <td>{!accInformation.Name}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <td>{!accInformation.Name}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <td>{!accInformation.BillingCountry}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>City, State Zip</th>
                        <td>{!accInformation.BillingCity}, {!accInformation.BillingState} {!accInformation.BillingStateCode}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <td>{!accInformation.PersonEmail}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <td>{!accInformation.Phone}</td>
                    </tr>
                </body>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div id="oppinnnerdivID">
            <table id="tableStyle_opp">
                <body>
                    <tr id="heading">
                        <th>Enduser Information:</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </body>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

With is code I am getting my pdf as
[image]

Please guide me what all i need to get the pdf working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS not working properly](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73025/css-not-working-properly)

Comment: not duplicate, it was css was not working. Here I it is working but not able to get the output what is need. Hope you read both questions properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div tags are generally discouraged with PDFs. The simple solution to your problem is to get rid of your `divs` and use a `Table align:left` and `Table align:right` for your two different tables.